# How to verify the requester of a Node API

Tags: node.js, security, cloudflare-workers

I have a Cloudflare Worker that presents a registration form, accepts input from the user that is posted back to the Worker which then sends that on to an Node HTTP API elsewhere (DigitalOcean if that matters) that inserts the data into a MongoDB (though it could be any database). I control the code in both the CF-Worker and the API.

I am looking for the best way to secure this. I am currently figuring to include a pre-shared secret key in the API call request headers and I have locked down what this particular API can do with database access control. Is there an additional way for me to confirm that only the CF Webworker can call the API?

If this is obvious to some I apologize. I have always been of the mind that unless you are REALY good at security it is best to consult those who are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can research OAuth2.0 standard. That is authorization standard for third party clients. Here is link: https://oauth.net/2/

This solution is the most professional.There are other less secure ways to do it, but easier to implement. Password and username, x-api-key, etc..

It sounds to me that you can also block all IPs and allow only requests from that specific domain name (CF Worker)